# Unable to render list view builder even when using expanded

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following where when I run it, I get the following error:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints
> are unbounded. RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#ad336
> NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

The issue seems to be coming from my ListView.builder.
The general suggestion from past questions such as [ListView.builder gives error: RenderBox was not laid out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55204328/listview-builder-gives-error-renderbox-was-not-laid-out)
has been to wrap it in an Expanded widget which I have done. But I am still seeing above error.

Could I please get some advice as to what I am doing wrong please. Thanks.

Pasting the whole file here in case there is some red herring going on.
The Expanded and ListView.builder section is at the end.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'account_details.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff020B2A),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xff020B2A),
          centerTitle: true,
          title: Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                'Account',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                'Card Ending - 00000',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 9,
                  letterSpacing: 1.1,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
              child: Icon(Icons.messenger_outline),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 30),
                  Text('Good Evening', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 12,
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(height: 18),
                  Text('NAME', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 28,
                  ),),
                  SizedBox(height: 18),
                  Text('Member Since \'18\'', style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white70,
                    fontSize: 10,
                  ),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, bottom: 16.0),
                    child: Text('Account', style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white70,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),),
                  ),
                ),
                
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true, // added after suggestion. same error
                    itemCount: accountTitles.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                        onTap: (){},
                        leading: Icon(accountTitles[index].leadingIcon),
                        title: Text(accountTitles[index].title),
                        trailing: Icon(accountTitles[index].trailingIcon),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The test data accountTitles coming from following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Info {
  final String title;
  final IconData leadingIcon;
  final IconData trailingIcon;

  Info({this.title, this.leadingIcon, this.trailingIcon});
}


List<Info> accountTitles = [
  Info(title: 'A', leadingIcon: Icons.chevron_left, trailingIcon: Icons.chevron_right),
  Info(title: 'B', leadingIcon:  Icons.chevron_left, trailingIcon: Icons.chevron_right),
  Info(title: 'C', leadingIcon:  Icons.chevron_left, trailingIcon: Icons.chevron_right),
];
```

Comment: Simple! just make `shrinkWrap: true` of your ListView.builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scrollable (`ListView` in this case) is rendered inside two nested `Column` so the general advice (use `Expanded`) is correct but you need to do it twice: both for the inner column and the list view. See it in action here https://dartpad.dev/855cbaf9d055104a04824b0f3bb5413d?null_safety=true